# While starting Squid on "cmd" it gives a "System error 1067 has occurred"

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I am trying to use Squid's (its 2.7STABLE8 version) reverse proxy service on Windows 7. When I try to start squid from "cmd" (as administrator) I get an error message such as;

"The Squid service could not be started

A system error has occurred

System error 1067 has occurred message

The process terminated unexpectedly"

To solve it I tried:

- setting "http_port" to 80 and 8080
- disabling user account control settings.
- and followed the instructions on this website: [Configuring a Basic Reverse Proxy in Squid on Windows](http://ashleyangell.com/2009/03/configuring-a-basic-reverse-proxy-in-squid-on-windows-website-accelerator/)

However, none of the solutions worked. Therefore if there is any other solution you might know it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my cache.log file, and it was reporting to;

"FATAL: ipcache_init: DNS name lookup tests failed"

Therefore, in the squid.conf file I set my dns_testname to;

"dns_testnames 0.0.0.0"

and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check:

```
squid -k check
```

I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone, I got the same problem and was low disk space.
I made some cleanup and went back on in seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when I check logs, I saw there is not "logs" folder under "c:\squid\var". after I create "logs" folder under there, it starts working. please make sure you have "c:\squid\var\logs"

Answer (score 0):

My error it was the same.
My solution was: check the log in C:\squid\var\logs in the file chache, and i found this;

commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 14 to 192.168.3.12:3128: (10049) WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL, Cannot assign requested address.
FATAL: Cannot open HTTP Port

In a last time, i change the dir IP of my server, this was the origin of my trouble. In the file C:\squid\etc\squid.conf i change it again, and it solve of my.